# How to update GUI using Tkinter on Python 3?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a text game in which I'm utilizing Tkinter for GUI in order to display the player's stats. If anyone could help me with a method to update the GUI every few seconds to show up-to-date stats it would be much appreciated. I'll post the code now:

```
def Stats(): # The function for the GUI, used later in threading
global name
global strength
global intel
global hp
global weapon
global weaponBonus
global armour
global defence
stats = tkinter.Tk()
stats.title ("Stats")
nameLabel = tkinter.Label(stats, text=" Name = %s " % name, font=("Papyrus", 16), bg="#c29970")
hpLabel = tkinter.Label(stats, text=" HP = %s " % hp, font=("Papyrus", 16), bg="#ba8c5f")
strengthLabel = tkinter.Label(stats, text=" Strength = %s " % strength, font=("Papyrus", 16), bg="#b27f4d")
intelLabel = tkinter.Label(stats, text=" Intelligence = %s " % intel, font=("Papyrus", 16), bg="#a07245")
weaponLabel = tkinter.Label(stats, text=" Weapon = %s (Strength Bonus = %s) " % (weapon, weaponBonus), font=("Papyrus", 16), bg="#8f663d")
armourLabel = tkinter.Label(stats, text=" Armour = %s (Defence = %s) " % (armour, defence), font=("Papyrus", 16), bg="#7d5935")
nameLabel.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
hpLabel.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
strengthLabel.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
intelLabel.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
weaponLabel.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
armourLabel.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
stats.mainloop()

StatsRun = threading.Thread(target = Stats) # The threading program
StatsRun.start()
```

Comment: Why are you using threading?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 so that the GUI can run alongside the main game.

Comment: You'll have a much easier time if you build an ordinary Tkinter app, even if you import the game's model and use it that way.

Comment: Call a function to update the labels every time one of the stats changes (we don't know how that happens).  See "Dynamical Content in a Label" at http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_labels.php = call a function and update a label every second.